# Best practice for calling objects that are private members of a class?

Tags: c++

How do you call functions for an object that is a private member of a class? I'm a bit rusty on my C++ so I'm pretty sure I started over thinking this and dug myself into a hole.

To brush up on my C++ I'm creating a program that lists a few different dice games, the user selects the game they would like to play and the number of players. Each game has dice with varying number of sides and different rules so I thought the best approach would be to create a class for each game, then store player and die objects in the class but I can't figure out how exactly I should access the player or object functions. Here's some example code.

Farkle.h

```
#ifndef FARKLE_FARKLE_H
#define FARKLE_FARKLE_H
#include "Player.h"
#include "Die.h"

class Farkle {
public:

    Farkle();

    void setPlayers(int t_numPlayers);
    std::string getPlayers(int t_playerNum); // probably don't need


private:
    std::vector<Player> m_playerList;
    Die m_die;
    
};


#endif //FARKLE_FARKLE_H
```

Farkle.cpp

```
#include "Farkle.h"
#include "Die.h"

Farkle::Farkle() {
    m_die = Die(6);
}

void Farkle::setPlayers(int t_numPlayers) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < t_numPlayers; i++){
        m_playerList.emplace_back(Player(("Player " + std::to_string(i + 1))));
    }
}

std::string Farkle::getPlayers(int t_num){
   return m_playerList[t_num].GetPlayerName();

}
```

Player.h

```
#ifndef FARKLE_PLAYER_H
#define FARKLE_PLAYER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Player {
public:

    // constructor
    Player(std::string t_playerName);

    // setters
    void SetPlayerName(std::string t_playerName);
    void SetPlayerScore(int t_score);

    // getters
    std::string GetPlayerName();
    int GetPlayerScore();  

private:

    std::string m_playerName;
    int m_score;
};


#endif //FARKLE_PLAYER_H
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(std::string t_playerName){
    m_playerName = t_playerName;
    m_score = 0;
}

// set the players name
void Player::SetPlayerName(std::string t_playerName){
    m_playerName = t_playerName;
}

// set the players score
void Player:: SetPlayerScore(int t_score){
    m_score = t_score;
}

// get the name of the player
std::string Player::GetPlayerName() {
    return m_playerName;
}

// get the players score
int Player::GetPlayerScore() {
    return m_score;
}
```

Die.h

```
#ifndef FARKLE_DIE_H
#define FARKLE_DIE_H


class Die {
    
public:
    explicit Die(int = 6);
    void roll();
    int getSides();
    int getValue();

private:
    int m_sides;
    int m_value;

};


#endif //FARKLE_DIE_H
```

Die.cpp

```
#include "Die.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

Die::Die(int t_numSides){
    unsigned int seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    m_sides = t_numSides;
    roll();
}

void Die::roll(){
    const int MIN_VALUE = 1;
    m_value = (rand() % (m_sides - MIN_VALUE +1)) + MIN_VALUE;
}

int Die::getSides() {
    return m_sides;
}

int Die::getValue() {
    return m_value;
}
```

Just want to note that these classes aren't close to done, I just wanted to figure my approach before putting more work into them.

Currently there are two ways to go about this that I know of but they just don't seem right. Again I could be over thinking this.

1. I know I can create a function in Farkle that calls a function for one of the objects like I did in with the getPlayers function in Farkle.cpp to get a players name. To me though this approach feels a bit silly since I'm just using the function to call another classes function.
2. I know I could also make the object a public member of the class. For example I could move "Die m_die;" to the public section of Farkle and then call a function later with "game.die.getValue()". I feel like this approach though isn't best practice and should probably be avoided. I couldn't find much information on it though so I could be incorrect.

Which approach would be best practice?

Is there another approach that I could be missing?

Instead of creating a class for each game type would it be better to use something else like a namespace (not too familiar with that) or a function?

Comment: The easiest thing might be to just create a public function in Farkle for rolling, and have the players register themselves to the specific game object, i.e., hold a pointer to the Farkle game they are in; this would allow the Players to call public Farkle functions. I also take issue with your Die contructor. Your entire program should seed only once. Ever. You reseed every time a die is created, and that's likely all during the same second of time, meaning all your die can behave the same. You need **one** PRNG for your entire program.

Comment: Reading up on your description, it seems that you're going to want a Base class for your dice games to inherit from as well.

Comment: Normally you do not want to give access to private member functions or variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this will be long-ish, but here's code to demonstrate what I mentioned in my comments.

We'll start with `main.cpp` though:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include "DiceGame.hpp"
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "TestGame.hpp"

int main() {
  Player one("Gus");
  Player two("Pat");
  std::unique_ptr<DiceGame> game(new TestGame);

  game->set_up();
  game->register_player(one);
  game->register_player(two);

  // Game loop would go here instead
  one.take_turn();
  two.take_turn();

  // When a game finishes, you'd clean up so you can play another
}
```

Our players can play many games, so they exist here. When a game is chosen, we set it up and associate our players with it. I then have each player take a single turn, but you could place a game loop here, or have the game be in charge of its loop, or have a `GameMaster` type class that ensures it's played.

Next, I said I didn't like the `Die` class because of how it did its random numbers. Here's a different take:

```cpp
#ifndef DIE_HPP
#define DIE_HPP

#include <random>

class Die {
 public:
  explicit Die();
  explicit Die(int sides);
  int roll();

 private:
  int m_sides = 6;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> m_values;
  static std::mt19937 m_roller;
};

#endif
```

The `static` member exists for all members of `Die` as a single entity. In other words, all `Die` objects share this single resource. Each `Die` does have its own distribution, allowing you to easily add whatever dice your game needs.

```cpp
// Die.cpp

#include "Die.hpp"

#include <random>

// static member initialization
std::mt19937 Die::m_roller{std::random_device{}()};

Die::Die() : m_values(1, m_sides) {}

Die::Die(int sides) : m_sides(sides), m_values(1, m_sides) {}

int Die::roll() { return m_values(m_roller); }
```

The `Player` class is able to interact with whatever game it's playing now.

```cpp
#ifndef PLAYER_HPP
#define PLAYER_HPP

#include <string>

class DiceGame;

class Player {
 public:
  Player(std::string name);
  int get_score() const;
  void set_score(int newScore);
  void set_game(DiceGame* game);
  void take_turn();

 private:
  std::string m_name;
  int m_score = 0;

  DiceGame* m_game = nullptr;
};

#endif
```

```cpp
// Player.cpp

#include "Player.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "DiceGame.hpp"

Player::Player(std::string name) : m_name(name) {}

int Player::get_score() const { return m_score; }

void Player::set_score(int newScore) { m_score = newScore; }

void Player::set_game(DiceGame* game) { m_game = game; }

void Player::take_turn() {
  std::cout << m_name << "'s turn:\n";
  m_game->roll();
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The final point raised in my comments is you'll likely want a base class since you said you plan on presenting different dice games that the user can choose from.

This creates a standard interface for all of your dice games, which will make their implementations a bit more straightforward.

We also register our `Player`s with the game they will be playing now. This allows your `Player`s to directly interact with whatever game they're currently playing.

```cpp
#ifndef DICEGAME_HPP
#define DICEGAME_HPP

#include <vector>

#include "Die.hpp"
#include "Player.hpp"

class DiceGame {
 public:
  DiceGame();
  virtual ~DiceGame();
  void set_up();
  void register_player(Player& player);
  void roll();

 protected:
  std::vector<Die> m_dice;
  std::vector<Player*> m_players;

  virtual void v_set_up() = 0;
};

#endif
```

```cpp
// DiceGame.cpp

#include "DiceGame.hpp"

#include <iostream>

DiceGame::DiceGame() = default;

DiceGame::~DiceGame() = default;

void DiceGame::set_up() { v_set_up(); }

void DiceGame::register_player(Player& player) {
  m_players.push_back(&player);
  player.set_game(this);
}

void DiceGame::roll() {
  for (auto& die : m_dice) {
    std::cout << die.roll() << " ";
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Finally, I created a super-basic test game to ensure all the pieces were playing nicely with each other. The game gives itself 6 d6s.

```cpp
#ifndef TESTGAME_HPP
#define TESTGAME_HPP

#include "DiceGame.hpp"

class TestGame : public DiceGame {
 public:
  TestGame();

 private:
  void v_set_up() override;
};

#endif
```

```cpp
#include "TestGame.hpp"

#include "DiceGame.hpp"

TestGame::TestGame() = default;

void TestGame::v_set_up() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    m_dice.emplace_back(6);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Gus's turn:
2 2 2 6 3 5 

Pat's turn:
3 3 3 5 1 3
```

There's a lot that's left out, like a proper game loop mechanism, and clean-up steps, but it should suffice to illustrate how you can create a relationship between the `Player` and the game they have chosen to play.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for not only answering the question in your original comment, but taking the time to type out such a detailed explanation. Would you also be able to give me some additional detail how static member initialization works? The Die class I provided was actually taken directly from the C++ book I used back in college so it didn't even cross my mind that seeding should only be done once and that there was something else I could use in its place.

Comment: It works the way I've shown. If you need more details I'd recommend searching [c++] for "good books" and getting one of those. Online resources for C++ aren't the most consistent, but the good books are.